# Trigger Jenkins job when new artifact is uploaded to Nexus3 repo

Tags: jenkins, nexus, nexus3

I'm quite new to Nexus3. I've set up a repository in Nexus3 and uploaded some artifacts.

My requirement is like I want a Jenkins job to be triggered up on new artifact upload in my Nexus repository. I had used [URLTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin) plugin with Artifactory earlier to achieve the above requirement. But I'm not sure how to use it with Nexus3. Also would like to see if there's any other option.

Can someone please help ?

**Raj**

Comment: Hi, Did you accomplish this?